# Converting an array of jQuery cloned virtual elements into a single object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following:

I have a template function that generates a block of HTML text and I have some simple data.

```
function template(item) {
    let HTML = `<div>`;
    HTML += `<span>${item}</span>`;
    HTML += `</div>`;
    return HTML;
}

var data = [
    { name: 'foo' },
    { name: 'bar' },
    { name: 'baz' },
];
```

For each of these items I want to create a jQuery clone because it's crucial for me to convert these items to actual HTML elements (DOM nodes) rather than plain text, so I do this:

```
var virtual_elements = [];

data.forEach(item => {
    let html = template(item.name);
    virtual_elements.push( $(html).clone(false) );
});
```

So I end up with an array of DOM objects, and each one of them can be used in conjunction with `$(target).append(element)` or `$(element).appendTo(target)` later on.

However, what I am trying to achieve is to turn all of them into a single object that can also be appended somewhere.

Is there a way to create some kind of an empty jQuery object that you can append to? I have tried the following:

```
var final = $();

virtual_elements.forEach(item => {
    $(final).append(item);
});
```

or

```
var final = $();

virtual_elements.forEach(item => {
    $(item).appendTo(final);
});
```

But both of these result in an empty object.

I have also tried this:

```
var final;

virtual_elements.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (index === 0) { final = item; }
    else { $(item).insertAfter(final) }
});
```

But it results in an object with a single item in it.

---

PS: Gluing all the normal text together and then using `$.parseHTML` is not an option for me because I need to run jQuery methods in each items inside of my data, which are only available for DOM nodes rather than plain text. For sake of simplicity I have left that out from the code, but a simple example would be (after cloning the element):

```
$(some-item).attr('src', '<iframe src="youtube.com/blabla" and some other unescaped single or double quotes here>');
```

---

**EDIT:** Much simplified example.

If I have this:

```
var one = $('<div><span>foo</span></div>').clone();
var two = $('<div><span>foo</span></div>').clone();
var three = $('<div><span>foo</span></div>').clone();

/// store these objects and do something with them.
```

Later - how do I turn this into a single jQuery object with 3 top-level keys for each element? The equivalent of having the same end result as doing this:

```
var all = $('<div><span>foo</span></div><div><span>bar</span></div><div><span>baz</span></div>').clone();
```

---

**SOLUTION**: Found a solution, not the most elegant but it works.

```
data.forEach(item => {
    let html = template(item.name);
    virtual_elements.push( $(html).clone(false)[0] ); // add [0] store as plain javascript object here
    virtual_elements.push( $.parseHTML(html) ); // this also works
});
```

After that create the final object:

```
var final = {};

elements.forEach((item, index) => {
    final[index] = item;
});
```

and you can use methods such as `$(final).replaceWith(target)` or `$(target).append(final)`

Comment: [`$.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) or simply `$(data.map(x => template(x.name)))`

Comment: @Andreas I need to manipulate the objects after cloning them first, so I can not use the map function directly. Also, where exactly are you suggesting that I use `$.add()`, on an empty `var final = $()` object?

Comment: The `$(html).clone(false)` part makes no sense. `$(html)` converts the markup in `html` into actual DOM nodes (wrapped in a jQuery object). You then clone them, and only store the clones. The elements created with `$(html)` are then discarded... `const virtual_elements = $(data.map(x => $(template(x.name))))` does the exact same thing.

Comment: @Andreas `$(html)` is not a jQuery method. The `html` inside of `$()` is a variable I declare in my forEach loop. I think you're misunderstanding my code. Also, check the PS part of my question. I first need to turn this plain text into DOM nodes so I can use jQuery manipulation methods on each item. After all of that is done I end up with 3 or more jQuery objects which I need to turn into one.

Comment: _" need to turn this plain text into DOM nodes"_ - That's already happening with `$(html)`

Comment: @Andreas can you check my edit please? This got a little confusing.